# nested for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to extract a string property from inside a complex javascript object.

Here is my scenario:

```
for (var key in results) {
    console.log(results[key]);
        ...results[key] is an object that returns few arrays and properties
            ...i need to capture an array inside named "all_names"
                ...again loop through all the objects in the array "all_names"
                    ...all the objects have a property name called "first_name"
                        ...i need to capture the "first_name" that have the value "Paul"

}
```

Sample Data:

After console.log(results[key]);
    "all_names" : Array[7]
    address: "Some Address"
    org_number: "TV146"

Then loop through"all_names"
    "first_name": "Paul"
    "last_name": "Henson"

Capture "Paul"

Please help.

Comment: Can you post some sample data set and the exact output you are expecting?

Comment: Do you just want to to return a single string or an array of strings? Do you just want a long list of `'Paul'`s to be returned? or do you want to return Paul's additional data?

Comment: @Aron just single string

Comment: @good.learner - Do you simply need to check whether Paul exists somewhere in the object? Because if you simply need single string just return it, why to go through all of this trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an array property, you can use `for (var x in arr)` as you have with results.  Without an example object, going from your description, you have:

```
results[].all_names[].first_name
```

which gives

```
for (var key in results)
{
    //...results[key] is an object that returns few arrays and properties
    //...I need to capture an array inside named "all_names"
    //...loop through all the objects in the array "all_names"
    for (var namekey in results[key].all_names)
    {
        // all the objects have a property name called "first_name"
        // ...i need to capture the "first_name" that have the value "Paul"
        if (results[key].all_names[namekey].first_name == 'Paul') {
            // will always be "Paul" 
            console.log(results[key].all_names[namekey].first_name); 

            //perhaps: console.log(key); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for...in` loops through keys not values! Since `results[key].all_names` is an array, `name` will be `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, ...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for the reminder.  I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in results) {
    results[key]["all_names"].forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj["first_name"] === "Paul") {
            // this is Paul
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Or just `results[key].all_names` and `obj.first_name`!